# Como corrigir o erro de armazenar valores de um Select em uma Array?

Tags: php

Eu tenho essa lista

```
$lista_datas = ["2020/02/17","02/04/2020","02/05/2020"];
```

Funciona perfeitamente no meu sistema deta forma.
Recentemente estou necessitando que os valores desta lista venham de uma coluna específica do banco de dados (coluna XDaTas), que contém outras datas. O código não funciona.
Veja o que estou tentando fazer para buscar os valores e armazenar nesta lista.

```
$sql = "SELECT data FROM basededados";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lista_datas = $row['XDaTas'];

        }}
```

Como posso resolver essa situação, para obter a consulta do banco de dados no formato descrito no início desta pergunta ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se `$lista_datas` é um array, então tem que usar o `[]` ou `array_push`, assim:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $lista_datas[] = $row['XDaTas'];
}
```

Ou com a função:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($lista_datas, $row['XDaTas']);
}
```

O resultado é o mesmo em ambos. Isso é o básico do básico, está muito bem explicado na documentação (essa é página que ensina o básico de como as arrays se comportam no PHP especificamente):

- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Não adianta programar orientado a chutes se existe um textos que já explica, o local exato esta em:

- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Tudo que for tentar dê uma estudada primeiro, tem exemplo pronto e intuitivos.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, funcionou. Terei mais atenção, abraços ...